# Error : JVM args ignored when same JVM is used

Tags: java, ant, jvm

Running the following ant script gives me this error message :

```
[java] Server ready
     [java] JVM args ignored when same JVM is used.
     [java] org.apache.tools.ant.ExitException: Permission ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "exitVM") was not granted.
```

My build.xml file :

```
<project name="tk1">
    <dirname property="basedir" file="${ant.file}" />
    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${basedir}/bin" />
        <javac srcdir="${basedir}/src" destdir="${basedir}/bin" />
    </target>
    <target name="clean" description="cleanup module">
        <delete dir="${basedir}/bin" />
    </target>
    <target name="run" depends="compile">
        <parallel>
            <java classpath="${basedir}/bin" classname="de.tk1.g4.ta1.server.MainServer" fork="true">
                <jvmarg value="-Djava.security.policy=server.policy" />
            </java>
            <sequential>
                <sleep seconds="2" />
                <java classpath="${basedir}/bin" classname="de.tk1.g4.ta1.client.MainClient">
                    <jvmarg value="-Djava.security.policy=client.policy" />
                    <arg value="39001" />
                    <arg value="Thomas" />
                </java>
            </sequential>
            <sequential>
                <sleep seconds="3" />
                <java classpath="${basedir}/bin" classname="de.tk1.g4.ta1.client.MainClient" fork="true">
                    <jvmarg value="-Djava.security.policy=client.policy" />
                    <arg value="39002" />
                    <arg value="Chris" />
                </java>
            </sequential>
        </parallel>
    </target>
    <target name="server" depends="compile">
        <java classpath="${basedir}/bin" classname="de.tk1.g4.ta1.server.MainServer" fork="true">
            <jvmarg value="-Djava.security.policy=server.policy" />
            <arg value="39001" />
            <arg value="Thomas" />
        </java>
    </target>
    <target name="client" depends="compile">
        <java classpath="${basedir}/bin" classname="de.tk1.g4.ta1.client.MainClient" fork="true">
            <jvmarg value="-Djava.security.policy=client.policy" />
            <arg value="39001" />
            <arg value="Thomas" />
        </java>
    </target>
</project>
```

I am trying to build a client/server application using RMI. I want to run one server instance and two clients. Am I missing something in my Ant script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `fork="true"` to `<java classpath="${basedir}/bin" classname="de.tk1.g4.ta1.client.MainClient">`, to let the client run in a separate JVM.